# scipy special function not receiving complex argument

Tags: python, scipy, complex-numbers

I tried to apply the inverse of the error function, `scipy.special.erfinv`, to a complex input and I received the following error :

```
from scipy.special import * 
z = 1j 
erfinv(z)
```

> TypeError: ufunc 'ndtri' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

I checked the ndtri function documentation and it's mentioned that the argument can be "real or complex".

Is the documentation correct ?

My final goal is to obtain the inverse of the imaginary error function which can be evaluated as follows: `erfi^-1(x) = -i * erf^-1(i*x)`

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Well the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.erfinv.html) do not mention that `erfinv()` input can be complex.

Comment: Yeah I apologize. What accepts complex values is the 'erf' function.
The scipy.special.ndtr in the docs says it accepts complex also but the inverse function (which is ndtri) mentions nothing.

Comment: You are confusing two scipy functions. The error is related to [ndtri](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.ndtri.html) and not [ndtr](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.ndtr.html)

Comment: No I know that.
So why ndtr accepts complex but the inverse don't ? 
Is there another way to get erfinv for complex values ?